# Why do "zend_is_executing(TSRMLS_C)" in get_active_function_name(TSRMLS_D) in Zend of PHP?

Tags: php

in Zend/zend_execute_API.c line 358 of PHP-5.2.17

Why do "zend_is_executing(TSRMLS_C)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check out the source, you see that `get_active_function_name` tries to access the executor global `function_state_ptr`.

The problem is, that this executor global is only initialized if the PHP code is actually executed. If, for example, an extension tries to call `get_active_function_name` before the `execute` function is called, the `get_active_function_name` could cause the PHP interpreter to crash if you omit the `zend_is_executing`-check.

So the check prevents `get_active_function_name` from accessing an uninitialized value which in turn could cause big problems (which is just another way of saying "undefined behaviour").